# How to create csv/excel file from response data reactjs

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, html-table

I have response data like below:

```
{
  "Aerospace": [
    {
      "id": 62,
      "branch": "Aerospace",
      "classification": "Einstufungen 2",
      "theme": "Produktentwicklung",
      "branch_id": 1,
      "classification_id": 1,
      "projectno": "510",
      "project_id": 52,
      "theme_id": 6,
      "projectname": "test 22",
      "comment": "",
      "customername": "test 12",
      "lead1id": 14,
      "lead1name": "DateTest",
      "lead1percent": "1000000000.0",
      "lead2id": 11,
      "lead2name": "logintest",
      "lead2percent": "2000000000.0",
      "lead3id": 16,
      "lead3name": "jomo",
      "lead3percent": "3000000000.0",
      "leadplan_probability": "100.0",
      "leadplan_plan2": "200.0",
      "leadplan_plan3": "300.0",
      "leadplan_addcosts": "500.0",
      "leadplan_fee": "400.0",
      "lead_plans": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "lead_id": 62,
          "addcosts": "500.0",
          "fee": "400.0",
          "plan2": "200.0",
          "plan3": "300.0",
          "probability": "100.0",
          "year": 2020
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "lead_id": 62,
          "addcosts": "600.0",
          "fee": "500.0",
          "plan2": "200.0",
          "plan3": "400.0",
          "probability": "100.0",
          "year": 2020
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "lead_id": 62,
          "addcosts": "500.0",
          "fee": "400.0",
          "plan2": "200.0",
          "plan3": "300.0",
          "probability": "100.0",
          "year": 2020
        }
      ],
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": 53,
          "lead_id": 62,
          "addcosts": "400.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "test5",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "test6",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-29",
          "fee": "200.0",
          "mail": "test",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-22",
          "paper": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "leadplan_plan2": 200,
      "leadplan_plan3": 300,
      "leadplan_addcosts": 500,
      "leadplan_fee": 400
    }
  ],
  "Electrical": [
    {
      "id": 65,
      "branch": "Electrical",
      "classification": "Einstufungen 2",
      "theme": "Sales",
      "branch_id": 2,
      "classification_id": 1,
      "projectno": "12345",
      "project_id": 53,
      "theme_id": 5,
      "projectname": "project12345",
      "comment": "test",
      "customername": "test123",
      "lead1id": 1,
      "lead1name": "alpha1",
      "lead1percent": "100.0",
      "lead2id": 53,
      "lead2name": "newuser",
      "lead2percent": "200.0",
      "lead3id": 51,
      "lead3name": "testisbah",
      "lead3percent": "300.0",
      "leadplan_probability": "1000.0",
      "leadplan_plan2": "200.0",
      "leadplan_plan3": "300.0",
      "leadplan_addcosts": "500.0",
      "leadplan_fee": "4000.0",
      "lead_plans": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "500.0",
          "fee": "4000.0",
          "plan2": "200.0",
          "plan3": "300.0",
          "probability": "1000.0",
          "year": 2020
        },
        {
          "id": 22,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "800.0",
          "fee": "700.0",
          "plan2": "500.0",
          "plan3": "600.0",
          "probability": "400.0",
          "year": 2023
        }
      ],
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": 52,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "400.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "4",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "4",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-20",
          "fee": "400.0",
          "mail": "4",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-20",
          "paper": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": 55,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "0.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-13",
          "fee": "0.0",
          "mail": "",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-14",
          "paper": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 57,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "0.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-31",
          "fee": "0.0",
          "mail": "",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-09",
          "paper": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 56,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "0.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-30",
          "fee": "100.0",
          "mail": "",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-14",
          "paper": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 58,
          "lead_id": 65,
          "addcosts": "0.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "",
          "decisiondate": "2020-05-06",
          "fee": "0.0",
          "mail": "",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-14",
          "paper": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "leadplan_plan2": 200,
      "leadplan_plan3": 300,
      "leadplan_addcosts": 500,
      "leadplan_fee": 4000
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to create an excel or CSV file from it but problem is that my data loads first and excel utility gives error related to null empty.

Is there any reasonable excel npm package from which I can export my data to csv/excel using button click in ReactJs?

If I would be able to export my complete table, that would be good.

The result excel view would be like:
[image]

Comment: Is It possible to do It on the back-end? Most of the time I would prefer doing this kind of thing on the server side.

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible, client wants to have it from client side ( react js ) so I am stuck on it!! I know but client says its more viable to use react js to do it.

Comment: Can you show us the script that loads the data? Would be helpful. Looking at what you said a solution could be to await for the response using an asynchronous function or a promise

Comment: I am using this code snipt in my code. https://codesandbox.io/s/14uvl?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LearningROR Did you find any solution ?